# Why my methods of working with arrays do not work in a class in ECMA6

Tags: javascript

1. The method for removing the product by the name "deleteProductByName" does not work
2. Method that returns the names of all the created products "getAllProductNames" does not work
3. The method that returns the total cost of all products "get totalProductsPrice" it should work as a "getter"
   Help please fix these methods

```js
class Product {
    constructor(name, count, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
class Shop extends Product {
    constructor(products) {
        super();
        this.products = [];
    }

    addProduct(newProduct) {
        this.products.push(newProduct);
    }

    deleteProductByName(productName) {
        let i = this.products.length;
        while (i--) {
            if (productName in this.products[i]) {
                this.products.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    getAllProductNames() {
        return this.products.map(object => Object.values(object)[0].name);
    }

    get totalProductsPrice() {
        return this.products.map(object => Object.values(object)[0].price).
        reduce((p, c) => p + c);
    }
}
const shop = new Shop();
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 1", 1, 200));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 1", 1, 500));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 2", 2, 1000));

console.log(shop.totalProductsPrice);
console.log(shop.getAllProductNames());
shop.deleteProductByName("product 2");
console.log(shop.products);
```

Comment: I don't think `productName in this.products[i]` does what you think it does.

Comment: Please post what you've tried and what you would have expected, along with what went wrong!

Comment: "*my methods of working with arrays do not work in a class in ECMA6*" - I don't see what this has to do with ES6 classes. Your methods of working with arrays don't work outside of `class` syntax either.

Comment: As an aside, you have a modelling problem. `class Shop extends Product` doesn't make sense -- a Shop isn't a kind of Product.

Comment: ok, what do you recommend to correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the reason why your script is not working is mostly due to your confusion on how to treat arrays. Note that your `this.products` is **an array of objects**. To answer your questions one-by-one:

## Q1: Removing the product by the name "deleteProductByName" does not work

That is because you are checking for the key (not the value) with your logic:

```
productName in this.products[i]
```

What you should do is to use this instead:

```
productName === this.products[i].name
```

## Q2: Method that returns the names of all the created products "getAllProductNames" does not work

That is because `object` in the predicate/callback actually refers to the individual `product` object. And this object has `name`, `count`, and `price` defined. Therefore, instead of doing what you did:

```
return this.products.map(object => Object.values(object)[0].name);
```

...using this will work (which is simply accessing the product's property/key using the dot notation):

```
return this.products.map(product => product.name);
```

## Q3: The method that returns the total cost of all products "get totalProductsPrice" it should work as a "getter"

It is defined as a getter correctly, but you have made the same mistake as detailed in Q2: you are not accessing the prices correctly. Instead of doing this:

```
return this.products.map(object => Object.values(object)[0].price).reduce((p, c) => p + c);
```

...you should be doing as such:

```
return this.products.map(product => product.price).reduce((p, c) => p + c);
```

---

See proof-of-concept example:

```js
class Product {
    constructor(name, count, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
class Shop extends Product {
    constructor(products) {
        super();
        this.products = [];
    }

    addProduct(newProduct) {
        this.products.push(newProduct);
    }

    deleteProductByName(productName) {
        let i = this.products.length;
        while (i--) {
            if (productName === this.products[i].name) {
                this.products.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    getAllProductNames() {
        return this.products.map(product => product.name);
    }

    get totalProductsPrice() {
        return this.products.map(product => product.price).reduce((p, c) => p + c);
    }
}
const shop = new Shop();
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 1", 1, 200));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 1", 1, 500));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 2", 2, 1000));

console.log(shop.totalProductsPrice);
console.log(shop.getAllProductNames());
shop.deleteProductByName("product 2");
console.log(shop.products);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Object.values(object)[0]` is a bad idea because Object.values is not guarantee to be in any particular order, the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) states:

> > in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop

And [for ... in documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) says:

> > A for...in loop iterates over the properties of an object in an arbitrary order (see the delete operator for more on why one cannot depend on the seeming orderliness of iteration, at least in a cross-browser setting).

Here is how you could do it:

```
getAllProductNames() {
    return this.products.map(p=>p.name);
}

get totalProductsPrice() {
    return this.products.map(p=>p.price).reduce((p, c) => p + c);
}
```

And to remove products you can use filer:

```
deleteProductByName(productName) {
    this.products = this.products.filter(p=>p.name!==productName);
}
```